# Dopesheet (motion tracking): Keyboard shortcut to jump to keyframe?

Tags: shortcut, tracking, dopesheet

I'm motion tracking a long shot (1000s of frames) with numerous tracks which are only valid for a portion of the footage. It's hard to discern if a track has stopped tracking because its gone out of shot, or because it needs some manual tweaking.

So I'm going through all my tracks in the dopesheet, one at a time, and trying to scrub the footage to the final keyframe to inspect it. This is quite fiddly. I expected I could click on a keyframe diamond to jump to that frame, but insted I have to manually scrub left and right to find the frame.

Looking through Preferences > Keymap and searching for `Keyframe` suggests I can use <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to "Jump to Keyframe", but when I try this in the Dopesheet view I see an error flash up at the bottom of the screen: `No more keyframes to jump to in this direction`

[image: Dopesheet keyframes in Motion Tracking view]

What's the best way to quickly navigate to keyframes when motion tracking?

Blender: v2.80.75